# EF Core JsonIgnore does not work with Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 6 and .NET 6.

I have added lazy loading to my ASP.NET Web API and I want to prevent a property from being serialized by using the `JsonIgnore` annotation on the property.

The reason for this is that I want to manage references in my entities via Guids and not the entities themselves. For example, when executing a GET HTTP request for one entity, the references to other entities are returned as ids. However, in my code below, I have the `NotMapped` property `UserRoleIds` and below that, the actual list of `UserRoles` being stored in the database. But when doing a GET request on one entity, the `UserRoleIds` and the `UserRoles` are returned.

I have two entity classes:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Guid> UserRoleIds 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (UserRoles == null)
                return new List<Guid>();
            else
                return UserRoles.ToList().ConvertAll(r => r.RoleId);  
        } 
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Role>? UserRoles { get; set; }
}   

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public RoleType RoleType { get; set; }
    
    // Navigation
    [Required]
    public Guid? RoleUserId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User? RoleUser { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DbContext:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext (DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }

    public DbSet<User>? User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role>? Role { get; set; }
}
```

This is my endpoint to get a single user:

```
// GET: api/Users/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUser(Guid id)
{
        if (_context.User == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var user = await _context.User.FindAsync(id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return user;
}
```

Now, to the result - the desired response body would be:

```
{
    "userId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "userName": "string",
    "userRoleIds": [
      "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    ]
}
```

But the actual response body looks like this for now:

```
{
  "userRoles": [
    {
      "roleId": "edd77715-f330-4662-1074-08da495846f4",
      "roleName": "Role1",
      "roleType": 0,
      "roleUserId": "2580b874-3465-40ca-2c81-08da49583a45"
    }
  ],
  "lazyLoader": {},
  "userId": "2580b874-3465-40ca-2c81-08da49583a45",
  "userName": "User1",
  "userRoleIds": [
    "edd77715-f330-4662-1074-08da495846f4"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the `UserRoles` are serialized even with the `JsonIgnore` annotation in place. It seems like I receive the lazy loading proxy object and not the actual object.

Oddly enough, when getting all users, everything seems to work fine:

My "get all users" endpoint:

```
// GET: api/Users
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUser()
{
        if (_context.User == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return await _context.User.ToListAsync();
}
```

The response body:

```
[
  {
    "userId": "2580b874-3465-40ca-2c81-08da49583a45",
    "userName": "User1",
    "userRoleIds": [
      "edd77715-f330-4662-1074-08da495846f4"
    ]
  }
]
```

In this case, the `UserRoles` property is not serialized, as expected.

Comment: **Do not use EF Entity types as DTOs nor as ASP.NET ViewModels for `<form>` binding** - it's why you're running into these problems. You _need_ to have entirely separate `class` types for DTOs and for ASP.NET Core MVC's `ModelBinding` (i.e. `<form>`, tag-helpers, `IHtmlHelper`, etc) - and they'll all end-up being versioned separately too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, that was [fixed for EF Core 7](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/28084/files). Do not expect a fix for EF Core 6.